# vBScript Parameterized Query - No Value Given for One Or More Required Parameters

Tags: vbscript, parameterized

I am  trying to create a parameterized query in vBScript. The code is as follows:

```
flow_order_volume(idx) = arr(0)
msgbox flow_order_volume(idx) 
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE NOMIMPORT.dbo.tblNOMIMPORT SET FlowOrderVolume = ?, FlowOrderMMBTU = 30, NomVolume = 40, NomMMBTU = 50 WHERE FullName= 'TEXT'"
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("floworder",adNumeric,,2000,flow_order_volume(idx))
msgbox param
Set adoCMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.Parameters.Append param
cmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objRecordSet.Open cmd
```

Each time I use a message box to print the value of the variable it returns "2", which it should. But then I receive the following error:

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

I do not understand why this is if the param variable shows the correct number when printed. The data type of this column for the database is "numeric(10, 5)".

I have also tried changing the flow_order_volume(idx) value to a static number just for trouble shooting purposes, and the same issue happens. If I hard code a value into the update statement, the update statement works fine.

Left off part of my code and fixed a typo. The new error message I get is:

```
Parameter object improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Numeric data types, you need to also define the scale and precision:

```
Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter(Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)
prm.Precision = numberOfDigits
prm.NumericScale = numberOfDecimalPlace
```

There is more info here for the other data types: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209%28v=vs.85%29.aspx